# What's wrong with this code? It's returning an unexpected token for the comparisons

Tags: javascript

```
  const compareGuesses = (human, computerGuess, generateTarget) => 
  {
    if
     (math.abs(human - generateTarger)) > (math.abs(computerGuess - generateTarget)) 
     return true;
  } 

    else if 
    {
      (math.abs(human - generateTarget)) > (math.abs(computerGuess - generateTarget))
      return false;
    } 
    else if 
    {
      human === computerGuess return true;
    }
```

It's just a simple game to compare your number to a randomly generated number and decide if you or the computers random guess is closer to the randomly generated target number

Comment: If you'll indent the code correctly you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: its not a good practice have too many return inside the if, it's better to use a variable and then return that variable, also it's easier to debug your code that way.

Comment: You have mismatched curly braces and `if` clauses without conditions.

Comment: `if` conditions don't go inside curly braces, and you close some of them in weird places anyway. Definitely try cleaning up your formatting, you'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 0):

```
const compareGuesses = (human, computerGuess, generateTarget) => {
    if ((math.abs(human - generateTarger)) > (math.abs(computerGuess - generateTarget))) { 
        return true;
    }
    else if ((math.abs(human - generateTarget)) > (math.abs(computerGuess - generateTarget))) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (human === computerGuess) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When working with if statements, the entire condition needs to be wrapped around a single set of parentheses.

Comment: Sorry but is the if block not wrapped in { }? Sorry I'm rather new to coding and just cannot seem to figure this out

Comment: The condition is wrapped in parentheses `(` and `)`, but the code to be executed when that condition is evaluated to true is wrapped in curly braces `{` and `}`

Comment: If you omit curly braces then JavaScript assumes that the conditional body is the following single-line statement. The parenthesis for the conditional expression though are always mandatory.